$2\cos^2\frac\theta{2}=1$ general solution for $\theta$
$2\cos^2\frac\theta{2}=1 \implies 1+\cos\theta=1 \implies \theta = (2n+1)\frac\pi2$.
But otherwise $\theta/2$ is $\frac\pi2$ and since $cos^2$ is periodic over $\pi$ we have $\frac\theta2=n\pi\pm\frac\pi4\implies$ $\theta=2n\pi\pm\frac\pi2$ (The answer given)
Why are these two results not same?

The solutions are the same, setwise. That is, if we define the sets $$S_1=\left\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\mid n\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$ $$S_2=\left\{2m\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\mid m\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$ Then $S_1=S_2$.
For a proof, note that when $n=0\bmod 2$, then $n=2m$ for some $m$ and hence $$(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}=(4m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}=2m\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$$ Similarly, when $n=1\bmod 2$, then $n=2m-1$ for some $m$ and hence $$(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}=(4m-1)\frac{\pi}{2}=2m\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and thus $S_1=S_2$.

I missed the $\pm.$
